# How to access a child component (from props.children) ref using functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use an `IntersectionObserver.observe()` on every single child component from a parent component, but for that I need their refs.

This is what my main component looks like:

```
// App component
<Nav>
  <Section ref={useRef(null)} {/* other props */} />
  <Section ref={useRef(null)} {/* other props */} />
  <Section ref={useRef(null)} {/* other props */} />
  <Section ref={useRef(null)} {/* other props */} />
</Nav>
```

I need the `Nav` component to access the ref of each `Section` component. I created the observer and got all children elements on a list:

```
// Nav component
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, options);

const sectionList: ReactElement<SectionProps>[] = [];
childrenToList(props.children, sectionList);

return (
  <>
    <nav className="nav">
      {/* ... */}
    </nav>
    {sectionList}
  </>
)
```

```
// Section component
const Section = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, SectionProps>((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <section ref={ref} {/* other attributes */}>{props.children}</section>
  );
});
```

This is what the `childrenToList` function is doing:

```
function childrenToList(children: ReactNode, listToPush: any[]) {
  React.Children.forEach(children, (element) => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(element)) return;

    listToPush.push(element);
  });
}
```

Then I need a way to do something like that (not an actual working code):

```
sectionList.forEach((section) => {observer.observe(section.ref.current)})
```

The problem is that I couldn't find a way to access the ref. I already tried having the ref as a prop, but it said it's value is null, or if I used with an if statement (like

```
const ref = section.props.ref
if (ref) {
  observer.observe(ref.current)
}
```

) the page simply wouldn't render and would remain blank.

Comment: Just set a ref for each Section the Nav component. You'll need to use [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) if setting refs on custom components

Comment: I've already set a ref for each section, the problem is that I don't know how to access them outside the `App` component, more specifically, inside a parent it's parent react component (`Nav`). When I try iterating over each `Section` element inside the `sectionList`, the only things I can access are `key`, `props` and `type`.
I'm adding these details to my question as well.